# Отправка формы (submit) нажатием клавиши enter

Tags: javascript, jquery

На странице сайта есть форма поиска

```html
<form name="searchForm" id="searchForm" action="/search" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="searchText">
  <button id="submit" type="submit"></button>
</form>
```

Как отправить форму (действие submit) по нажатию клавиши "enter", если фокус ввода не находится на элементах формы? Т.е. в какой бы части страницы пользователь не находился, при нажатии на enter нужно отправлять форму на сервер.

Comment: В дополнение к ответу ниже вам нужно изменить id  кнопки, на любой кроме submit

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй следующим образом. [Здесь](https://codernote.ru/jquery/sobytiya-jquery/submit/) рассказано как вызвать сабмит из кода, а [здесь](https://webformyself.com/kak-pojmat-sobytie-nazhatiya-enter-v-pole-input/) как отслеживать нажатие клавиши Enter

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode === 13) {
      $("#searchForm").submit();
    }
});
```

Comment: @PavelNazarian указан в метках, следовательно разницы нету что использовать

Comment: Да, указан, не заметил

Answer (score 0):

```
document.onkeydown = () => {
    if(e.keyCode === 13) {
        searchForm.submit();
    }
}
```